# Invalid call at line 41: require(item.image)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create screen with a FlatList by using my component but why couldn't find the reason why i get error. I also checked React native dev website  and see how FlatList works but still have no clue.
I'm pretty new at react native. Sorry if its very basic mistake.

The screen that im trying to create:

[image]

My component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";

const ScreenMap = (props) => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={props.path}>
                <Image source={props.imageSource} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default ScreenMap
```

Screen script:

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, Text, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import ScreenMap from '../components/ScreenMap'

const BaslicaScreen = () => {
    const contentButtons = [
        {
            title: "ilceler",
            image:'../../assets/Baslica/ilceler.png'
        },
        {
            title: "gururHuzurIlham",
            image: '../../assets/Baslica/gururHuzurIlham.png'
        },
        {
            title: "ulasim",
            image:'../../assets/Baslica/ulasim.png'
        },
        {
            title: "pratikBilgiler",
            image:'../../assets/Baslica/pratikBilgiler.png'
        },
        {
            title: "tarihiEserlerVeMuzeler",
            image:'../../assets/Baslica/tarihiEserlerVeMuzeler.png'
        },
        {
            title: "etkinlikler",
            image: '../../assets/Baslica/etkinlikler.png'
        },
        {
            title: "canakkaleyeOzgu",
            image:'../../assets/Baslica/canakkaleyeOzgu.png'
        },
        ]
    return (<View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            data={contentButtons}
            keyExtractor={contButton => contButton.title}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return <ScreenMap imageSource={require(item.image)} />
            }} 
        />
    </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(2,126,179,1)",
    },
});

export default BaslicaScreen
```

**Edit** i fixed it by changin array to this:

```
const contentButtons = [
    {
        title: "ilceler",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/ilceler.png')
    },
    {
        title: "gururHuzurIlham",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/gururHuzurIlham.png')
    },
    {
        title: "ulasim",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/ulasim.png')
    },
    {
        title: "pratikBilgiler",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/pratikBilgiler.png')
    },
    {
        title: "tarihiEserlerVeMuzeler",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/tarihiEserlerVeMuzeler.png')
    },
    {
        title: "etkinlikler",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/etkinlikler.png')
    },
    {
        title: "canakkaleyeOzgu",
        image: require('../../assets/Baslica/canakkaleyeOzgu.png')
    },
    ]
```

and return this :

```
return <ScreenMap imageSource={item.image} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass just image address and not object which is in require() form.
then put require(props.imageSource) inside of your ScreenMap and Image Component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did exactly same whatever you said. now on the Screen script, i return this 
return <ScreenMap imageSource={(item.image)} />

and on ScreenMap
<Image source={require(props.imageSource)} />

but now i get Invalid call at line 9: require(props.imageSource) error